# Installing PyQt4 on a virtual environment on mac

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I am trying to install PyQt4 on a virtual environment. 
First I installed SIP as such:

```
virtualenv --always-copy ve
ve/bin/activate
. ve/bin/activate
cd ~/Downloads
cd sip-4.16.9
python configure.py --incdir=../ve/include/python2.7
make 
make install
```

then I tried installing PyQt4 as:

```
cd ~/Downloads/PyQt-mac-gpl-4.11.4 
python configure-ng.py
```

However, I get an error:

```
Error: Use the --qmake argument to explicitly specify a working Qt qmake.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install QT on your machine. And then try installing PyQT4. Ensure that QT path is added to your environment PATH or you would need to give the QT path while installing PyQT(as the error in your post mentions).